# PHP script displays nothing when browser has run

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana

I'm learning how to use PHP. I'm trying to run a simple PHP script. But when I run it in Google Chrome, nothing is displayed. Here's my code:

```
<html>  
<body>  
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
?>
</html>
</body>
```

I'm running XAMMP Apache and the Eclipse Aptana plugin.

Comment: Make sure you close your tags in the right order. Also check the page source in your web browser to see if it's actually blank or not.

Comment: This is new try `<?php phpinfo();  ?>` and tell us if anything is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, you are closing your tags wrong, try

```
<html>  
<body>  
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

A cleaner better test would be

```
<html>  
<body>  
    <?PHP echo "<p>Hello World</p>"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure you have PHP installed as well. XAMPP is a great solution for local machine website hosting for testing things like PHP. It will install everything you need, and even gives you a nice service manager and more.

When testing in google chrome, right click on the page and click "inspect element", you can then see the pure HTML, and see what is really there.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: It worked. The tags were placed in the wrong manner.Thank you.